# Microsoft.Net.Compilers Package Error When Deployed

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, server, package, roslyn

I have an C# MVC project and I used to have version 1.0.0.0 of Microsoft.Net.Compilers installed in my project. But I recently updated it to the most recent version 2.6.1.0 as I needed it to do some newer code.

The problem arises when I deploy my new code out to the server. I get this weird unhelpful error:

[image]

If I remove the following code from my web.config the website will load but some pages that have the new code that I had to update the compiler for will fall over.

```
  <system.codedom>
<compilers>
  <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
  <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
</compilers>
```

And example of the error I get when I removed that part in the web.config is as follows:

Unexpected character '$' when doing the new string.format

```
$"Hello {Model.WorldText}";
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the Event Logger on the server and it reported an Error that stated there were features being used in my application that required .NET 4.6 to be installed on the server.

I had to do some windows updates as there were blockers on the .NET 4.6 update. Once that was done I was able to install .NET 4.6 and the site works like a charm again.